# Openable accordions side-by-side both expand when accordion clicked, how do I have only the clicked one open?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website for practice that has multiple expandable sections, some of which sit side-by-side. I have the accordions working but the desired behavior is when you click the button to expand one accordion, all others stay closed. At the moment this is technically true, but any sections that are beside the clicked accordion in the same row will have their divs expand to be the same size as the text in the clicked accordion.

Here's a Fiddle to show what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/jsfsmh/m5x08awc/1/ but you have to expand the result window to make sure the two Divs sit beside each other and not on top of one another. Here's the relevant inline JavaScript for the accordion:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                        panel.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        panel.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I'm sure there's something fairly obvious I could do here but I've been working at it for days and I'm at a loss. I'm a beginner at JavaScript and I'd say maybe novice level at CSS/HTML. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with one line of css!

The problem is that flexbox applies a bunch of standard rules when you go display:flex and one of them is align-items: stretch, which makes the smaller flexbox items automatically size up to fill the space in the cross-axis (in this case the height). You can see what the options are here: [align-items](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)

To fix it, add the following

```
align-items: flex-start;
```

To your flexbox container.

Working JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eliashjelm/j40gb9y5/1/)

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick (and was as easy as I kept thinking it should be ;) )